# Roaming profile and diff hash

Tags: windows, active-directory, diff, profile, roaming

I was rebuilding a profile for a user and done it as follows:

Renamed profile.V2 to Profile.OLD then deleted his account on AD, made a new one.

User realised he didnt back up his files so i deleted his profile.V2 folder and restored the .OLD by renaming it back to profile.V2 which didnt work. Sys admin told me that profiles are synced using hash diffsand every profile has it’s own diff base so when it changed it stopped.

User still asking about files and the sys admin guys off today. Is there anything else i can do or is he out of luck?

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you should not delete the AD account.  Renaming the profile on the machine would have been enough to have it recreate it when he logged in.  With the new account, the group memberships and permissions have to be rebuilt.

As far as the profile, if he is an Admin on his computer, he could just access the profile and copy over his documents.  If he isn't, he could log on to create his new profile and then you could log in and move the documents into his new profile for him (or just give him access to the folder).